# ContactManager Sample Code displays odd account

Tags: android, accounts

I created a project from the ContactManager sample code and installed it on my DX.  When I click the account spinner, in addition to the 2 accounts I have on the device, it displays 33 seemingly random characters followed by "@random.svcmot.com".

Does anyone know what this account is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [svcmot.com](https://portal-blur.svcmot.com/blur-web-portal-1.0/?x=yncDX3QajxysvYmZri33rQ) relates to MOTOBLUR, the custom UI/social integration present on the Droid X.  It's probably related to the way some of the MOTOBLUR synchronization and background processing works.

From the [consumer MOTOBLUR site](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/MOTOBLUR/Meet-MOTOBLUR):

> With MOTOBLUR, your data is continually backed up.

and

> Email, pics, social media posts – MOTOBLUR syncs them all with automatic, continuous updates to your phone.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  Since the user doesn't need to know about that account (at least, I don't think so), I can exclude it from my spinner.

Answer (score -1):

The seemingly random characters the IMEI/ESN/MEID for your phone, followed by some other characters. I'm not entirely sure, if you pull up the phone info panel you can see them under Motorola Services. I think it may have to do with the way the phone transfer/receives data, but I am really not sure.